# Webpack build produces blank page

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I've got a webpack project using Angular and I've ran a production build (everything has built fine) but when it comes to running the built application in the browser, the page is just blank. I'm using ngRouter in my project so I'm wondering if that's the issue but honestly don't know where to even start debugging this because there are no console errors or anything. My CSS is loading fine so I'm not entirely sure what the issue could be.

Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: did you solve the problem? I am having the same issue now. With npm start the app works perfectly, but when I build it with npm run build than I am getting a gray page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your issue is/was the same as mine, but checkout my post over here - the solution was that I was specifying my html file in the webpack config's entry point... [Webpack production build does not load anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913095/webpack-production-build-does-not-load-anything)