# Webpack production build does not load anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, production

I've been working on an app using React and Webpack for a little while. My development environment works fine, and everything loads properly using webpack-dev-server.

I decided to run a production build of the application to see what the end-product might look like size-wise and observe the general output of the webpack product build.

It turns out that running `webpack -p`, while it does produce output (more on that in a minute), does not load anything at all when I hit the site in a browser.. A quick check of the output tells me that none of my component code is making it into the `webpack -p` build.

The images and HTML copy over as they exist in my src (dev) folder, however my JS bundle output is extremely small - the file (main.js) is only 246 bytes.

Here is the output from running webpack -p

```
$ npm run build

> project@0.1.0 build /Users/me/Development/project
> NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --bail --progress --config webpack.config.babel.js

Hash: 9e5f6974ce21c920a375
Version: webpack 1.12.10
Time: 2003ms
            Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
       index.html    1.45 kB          [emitted]
  images/edit.svg  524 bytes          [emitted]
images/search.svg    1.19 kB          [emitted]
          main.js  246 bytes    0, 1  [emitted]  javascript, html
    + 219 hidden modules
```

When I run the development version of the project, the output is markedly different... I know that the dev server dependencies are in there, and the code is not minified.. And, most importantly - everything works as expected when running the dev server.

```
$ npm start

> project@0.1.0 start /Users/me/Development/project
> webpack-dev-server --hot --display-modules --config webpack.config.babel.js

http://localhost:3333/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from /Users/me/Development/project/dist
Hash: 1b34ed58f9e323966ada
Version: webpack 1.12.10
Time: 2745ms
            Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
       index.html    1.45 kB          [emitted]
  images/edit.svg  524 bytes          [emitted]
images/search.svg    1.19 kB          [emitted]
          main.js    1.54 MB    0, 1  [emitted]  html, javascript
```

Here's my webpack.config.babel.js file:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';

import ModernizrWebpackPlugin from 'modernizr-webpack-plugin';
import modernizrConfig from './modernizr.config';

const appDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');
const distDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './dist');
const nodeModulesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules');

const excludeDirs = /(node_modules|bower_components)/;

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        javascript: appDir + '/main.js',
        html: appDir + '/index.html'
    },
    output: {
        path: distDir,
        filename: 'main.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: distDir,
        inline: true,
        port: 3333
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6'],
        modulesDirectories: [
            'node_modules',
            './src'
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js'),
        // new ModernizrWebpackPlugin(modernizrConfig),
    ],
    sassLoader: {
        sourceMap: false,
        includePaths: [
            appDir,
            nodeModulesDir,
            nodeModulesDir + '/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/',
            nodeModulesDir + '/susy/sass'
        ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { // js/jsx
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: excludeDirs,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: [
                        'es2015', 'react'
                    ]
                }
            },
            { // html
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: excludeDirs,
                loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'
            },
            { // images
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
                exclude: excludeDirs,
                loader: 'file?name=images/[name].[ext]'
            },
            { // sass
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: excludeDirs,
                loader: 'style!css!sass'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't think I've got a particularly complex, or uncommon setup, and I've tried changing everything from es2015/es6 to commonJS already as well, with the same result.

I'm at a loss as to what the issue could possibly be here; hoping that someone can point out some obvious error I've got, or perhaps suggest config updates/changes that could resolve this problem.

Thanks for taking the time to read everything!

Comment: I've been using webpack successfully for months now, and I've never come across using an HTML file as an entry point. Usually it's just a javascript file, which gets output to a `dist` folder or something similar, and then _that_ file gets included on some other HTML page somewhere.

Comment: Well, dang. That did the trick. I'm not sure why I had that in there, or where I got the idea to drop the HTML file in the entry point. Thanks for the quick-fix!

Comment: Can you convert that into an answer and accept it? Thanks. :)

Comment: Not sure how I can do that... unless your comment was directed towards @rossipedia :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I've been using webpack successfully for months now, and I've never come across using an HTML file as an entry point.

Usually you'll use Webpack to package up javascript, css, and sometimes images (ie: "assets") to be used *by* an html file. Serving that HTML file is outside the realm of Webpack's responsibility.

I would suggest using Webpack to generate *only* the final javascript bundle, then using some other method (ie: express, or some other web server) to serve that file and the html that consumes it.